# How do I add a new stereo or monocular camera to ROS?

Tags: ros, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Do I need to write my own "driver"? (That is code that interfaces with the camera APIs and publishes to ROS?)
- In that case, what do I publish?
- Do I give only raw image output or is there a way to publish a stereo pair?
- Are there any examples for how to do this, e.g. from some other stereo cameras?
- What is the easiest way to do this?

copied from ros-users thread: http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110215.125025.1315d930.en.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9063/how-do-i-add-a-new-stereo-or-monocular-camera-to-ros?/) by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8372 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Do I need to write my own "driver"?**

Yes, unless someone has already written one.

**That is code that interfaces with the camera APIs and publishes to ROS?**

Yes.

**In that case, what do I publish? Do I give only raw image output or is there a way to publish a stereo pair?**

There are standard ROS ways to publish stereo data.

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_pipeline

**Are there any examples for how to do this, e.g. from some other stereo cameras?**

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/bumblebee2
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/videre_stereo_cam

**What is the easiest way to do this?**

The extra ROS wrapping for publishing camera data does not involve
much additional code, but does require a basic understanding of the
image pipeline. So, study the interfaces and look at examples of other
drivers, then ask more questions.

Answers provided by Jack O'Quin

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some follow-up:

- The original requester reported that the device is a [VRMagic Multisensor](http://www.vrmagic.com/imaging/cameras-framegrabber/multi-sensor-cameras/).
- Stefan Kohlbrecher reported that his group is working on a driver for it (not yet published).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-10-05**:
Update: The camera driver is now indexed on ros.org: http://www.ros.org/wiki/vrmagic_camera

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-02-27**:
Update: A very basic version of the driver is now available, anyone who is interested please leave a comment here.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-02-18**:
This is indeed the case, I expect to have a very basic version publicly available in a few days and in a repo that still has to be created :)